# Emailing user works but not admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an order form that is processed and the customer receives the email, however, adding in the admin bit doesn't email the admin?

The following code is the bit that sends to the customer (which works fine) and also the code that **should** also email the admin but doesn't :(

```
    // email stuff (change data below)
    $to = $payment_data['sold_to_email']; 
    $from = $order_options['admin_email']; 
    $subject = "Your Order"; 

    //include the message
    $message = $order_options['email_message'];
    //Build the Order out
    $message .= '<br /><br />Thank you for purchasing from us';

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers  = "From: ". $company . " <" . $from . ">". $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

    // message
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    //$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

    // send message
    $sendit = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $admin_message = $payment_data['admin_field'];
    wp_mail($admin_email, 'New Order', $admin_message);

    //Code to troubleshoot email problems.
    /*  if(!$sendit) {
                $tempOptions = get_option('order_options');
                $tempOptions['admin_email'] = "EMAIL FAILED";
                update_option('order_options', $tempOptions);

            }
    */
```

Comment: //Code to troubleshoot email problems. << gives you an idea perhaps?

Comment: @Dagon: Thanks Dagon. Just the issue is that I have to go through the process of ordering which is quite lengthy, if I want to debug that way :( Was hoping someone could see if I made any coding error prior to having to go down that route.

Comment: Also, it sends from the admin email to the user email no problem. It's the extra code I added `$admin_message = $payment_data['admin_field']; wp_mail($admin_email, 'New Order', $admin_message);` that I'm trying to debug.

Comment: Is `$admin_email` is available through the script ?

Comment: Yep. Sending to the customers sends from the `$admin_email` address just fine :)

Comment: Hmmm just wondering, maybe I missed something. Should that line be `$sendit = wp_mail($admin_email, 'New Order', $admin_message);`, ie: missing the `$sendit = `?